# Outlook 2010 rendering differences?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, dynamics-crm-2011, outlook-2010

My colleague and I both have Outlook 2010 installed and we're using this with the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Outlook Client. When we view the same CRM web pages, we sometimes have web page rendering differences.

I know that Outlook 2010 uses the MS Word engine to render web pages, but what I don't understand is why his page layout breaks and mine not, while we both use the same version of Outlook on Windows 7.

For example, I created a custom web page with some button tags having images inside them. I used Twitter Bootstrap for the CSS. Recently I updated Bootstrap to the 2.0.4 version where they added a new property to img elements saying 'max-width: 100%;'. His button images width reduced to 0 (or at least not visible anymore), and mine where still 16px wide or so and visible. How come?

What could cause these differences? Please help.

Comment: There are some registry settings that can alter "IE rendering modes". I wonder if there is some such interaction?

Comment: Bootstrap for an _email_? You are asking for trouble. There's so much CSS in there it must be a nightmare to debug. Also, check and see what DPI you two have, if it's different it might be the source of some problems.

Comment: @TheZ I'm not talking about Html e-mails, but about web pages. The Crm outlook client enables you to open crm web pages from Outlook. It's a web app.

Comment: @mdocter Oh thanks for clearing that up, I'd still look into the DPI thing if I were you. I've had some really strange rendering inconsistencies across otherwise identical computers with different DPI settings and Outlook/MS Word Rendering.

Comment: @pst Would you happen to know which registry setting(s) that would be? And does that affect only IE or also MS Word?

Comment: @TheZ I know he has different DPI settings. His laptop is of a different type than mine. But what can I do about that fact. Our clients will also have all kinds of resolutions. How did you handle this problem?

Comment: @TheZ I understand. Tomorrow I'll give it a go. Thanx for your input!

Comment: @mdocter I would imagine it depends on if the IE rendering/COM engine is used (and I would imagine it is in the CRM add-in? not sure about normal Outlook "Web Views", though) .. but see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx

Comment: Compare your IE versions as well

Comment: Check you're both running the same version ( point release ) of IE.

Comment: @TheZ - Sorry for the late reply. The problem was indeed caused by the DPI settings of my colleague. Windows 7 sets these to ['Medium - 125%'](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/443-dpi-display-size-settings-change.html), so you were right. If you add a short answer to this question mentioning this, then I can mark it as the answer and you'll get your credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I've had trouble when sending from a computer with one DPI setting to another and I was even able to replicate the problem by switching DPI on the computer that was previously unaffected. So I'd check those settings first and compare.

Unfortunately I had to work around the problem and I never went back to find a good solution.

I agree that it could be because Outlook now renders html with the shared MS Office rendering engine. While this means that transferring word documents to and from outlook is more consistent, it also means that everything is rendered with MS Word's inches/points.